# How to create a ggplot bar chart with multiple columns of data for y?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

My dataset looks like this :

[image: Here's a sample of the dataset. Just want to plot the columns marked in yellow]

Here's a table with a sample of the data:

| City | AverageClientUsage | AverageClientEst | EstimatedTraffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | 2695.68 | 3555.62 | 2812.89 |
| Boston | 559.48 | 1080.49 | 583.81 |
| Chicago | 3314.44 | 5728 | 3458.56 |

I'd like ggplot to use City as the X axis and have three bars for each point on the x axis, one for AverageClientUsage, one for AverageClientEst, one for EstimatedTraffic. How do I go about doing this? At the end I'd like the ggplot to look like this:

[image: Plot created using Microsoft Excel]

Comment: Your chances of getting help will increase significantly if you include a reproducible example [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question, for example by sharing your data using `dput()` or part of it using `dput(head())`. Please do not share your data by means of a screenshot, since we cannot copy the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to `pivot_longer()` your dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(!City, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count")
```

Afterwards, you can create bars filled by Type, and `using position = "dodge"` within geom_col()

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = City, y = Count, fill = Type)) + # specify x and y axis, specify fill
         geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.6, color = "black") + # position.dodge sets the bars side by side
  theme_minimal() + # add a ggplot theme
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", # move legend to bottom
        legend.title = element_blank(), # remove legend title
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, color = "gray33"), # rotate x axis text by 45 degrees, center again, change color
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "gray33"), # change y axis text coor
        axis.title = element_blank(), # remove axis titles
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + # remove vertical grid lines
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "darkorange2", "gray")) # adjust the bar colors
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(City = c("Atlanta", "Boston", "Chicago"), AverageClientUsage = c(2695.68, 
      559.48, 3314.44), AverageClientEst = c(3555.62, 1080.49, 5728
      ), EstimatedTraffic = c(2812.89, 583.81, 3458.56)), class = c("tbl_df", 
      "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```